# Mahout "Inverse" Recommender

Tags: hadoop, mahout

With Mahout recommender (with Hadoop map reduce), the typical question is "which movies this particular user may be interested in?". How do we reverse that question and instead ask for "which users may be interested in this particular movie"?

And eventually to take it one step further: "for this list of movies, which users are the most suitable candidates?"

In reality this is not about movies, but to build a recommendation to pick top candidates with resources/preferences that most suitably meet a particular set of requirements.

Any thoughts how to solve this with Mahout, in particular using hadoop map-reduce jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip your data, so that users are items and vice versa. Then use it as before.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's a good solution for single-item recommendation. How to extend it to cover multiple items? E.g. "For a *list* of movies, which users are the most suitable candidates?" (The questions will make more sense if you substitute "movies" with "skills")

Comment: If you're familiar with Myrrix, this is what `recommendToMany` does: http://myrrix.com/rest-api/#recommendtomany Under the hood this is really just merging the feature vectors for several users and recommending to that combination. (Here of course you've flipped items and users). You can't do this in Mahout but it's something you might be able to build by hand.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's very helpful. And I hadn't actually heard of Myrrix before, I'll go and check it out